# Magento 2 - display "Not display individually" product on listing page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, catalog, visibility

I want to display "Not display individually" visibility product display on listing page. Please help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As it is not clear why you would want to specifically use 'Not display individually' products on listing page without an explanation, you may want to change visibility using MySQL so that they will display on category listing.

So depending you requirements, you can adjust them only to display in Catalog or Search or both.

*The values are:*

- **1** - Not Visible Individually: (Never visible, not even in Search)
- **2** - Catalog: (Visible on Category Page)
- **3** - Search: (Not Visible on Category Page, but appears in Search results)
- **4** - Catalog, Search: (Appears in both)

In order to bulk update '**visibility when 1**' you can run this update query:

`UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int AS cEnt SET cEnt.value = 4
WHERE attribute_id IN (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute ea WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'visibility')
AND cEnt.value = 1;`

Change `cEnt.Value = 4` to any option as per your requirements.

Then most likely run:
`bin/magento cache:flush`
`bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: I want load "Not display individually" visibility product on quick-view content product detail

Comment: Would the above solution not help?

Comment: Not work for me.